# Using Twitter node in Node-RED in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am a beginner in using Node-RED in Bluemix. I am trying to analyse the tweets along with sentiment analysis using sentiment node. Do we have an option to pass the tweet search keyword as a parameter? Also can we control (start/stop) the flow based on tweet count (for example I need to do the analysis of 500 tweets only)? I would like to know once the flow is deployed, will the flow start the tweet analysis until the session of the Node-RED flow editor is terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer each of your questions:

- You cannot pass the search text dynamically, you have to configure it in the node via the editor
- Once deployed, it connects to the [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) to start receiving the tweets that match your search criteria. There is no further control of the node available once it is deployed.
- Clicking "deploy" starts the flow running in your node-red instance. It is not tied to you having the editor open in a browser - you can close the browser window and your flows keep running in Bluemix